# How can I make the minikube dashboard answer on all ips 0.0.0.0?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

`minikube` has a dashboard that I can view easily with

```
minikube dashboard
```

However, that only works if I run it on my own machine because it only answers on localhost,

```
* Verifying dashboard health ...
* Launching proxy ...
* Verifying proxy health ...
* Opening http://127.0.0.1:35781/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ in your default browser...
  - http://127.0.0.1:35781/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

I'm running `minikube` though on a remote machine on openstack, so I need to address it by it's lan address, and not 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to background the dashboard,

```
$ minikube dashboard --url &
[1] 356972
```

And then use `kubectl` proxy to listen to all addresses,

```
kubectl proxy --address=0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts='.*'
```

Comment: how is this supposed to work if the URL I get is still the localhost 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Caterina it works because he's creating a proxy listening on 0.0.0.0